# Excel VBA reference a macro variable inside quotes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to reference a string macro variable insude quotes.

Here's what I have. Why couldn't it just be &state. Arrrggg!

Thanks

```
Dim state As String
state = "AK"
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "\\sac-psas-02\pm\ma\scott\OW\hpi trend pci outlier removal\lr_hpi_""" & state & """ .csv"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
"\\sac-psas-02\pm\ma\scott\OW\hpi trend pci outlier removal\lr_hpi_" & state & ".csv"
```

(You only need multiple " within a string when you want a " character)